# Field on Account to act as Rollup Summry field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to develop an apex trigger which will give me total amount of all child objects amount and it will act as a Roll up Summary field.
I am getting below error,

> Variable does not exist: AccountID at line 25 column 23

**Trigger**

```
trigger RollUpField on Contact (after insert,after update,after delete,after undelete) {


Map<ID,Double>counter=new Map<ID,Double>();
Set<ID> cids=new Set<ID>();
if(Trigger.isInsert||Trigger.isUpdate)
{
    for(Contact  c:Trigger.new)
    {
        cids.add(c.AccountID);
    }
}

if(Trigger.isDelete)
{
    for(Contact c:Trigger.old)
    {
        cids.add(c.AccountID);
    }

}

for(AggregateResult q:[Select AccountID,Sum(Count__c)Amount from Contact where AccountID IN:cids group by AccountID]);{

counter.put((ID)q.get(AccountID),(Double)q.get(Amount));


}

List<Account> acc=new List<Account>();

for(Account a:[Select id,Total_Amount__c from Account where ID IN:Cids])
{
    Double total=counter.get(a.id);
    a.Total_Amount__c =total;

    acc.add(a);
}

 update acc;  








}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is wrong:

This

```
counter.put((ID)q.get(AccountID),(Double)q.get(Amount));
```

needs to be

```
counter.put((ID)q.get('AccountID'),(Double)q.get('Amount'));
```

Comment: Got this error 'Loop with query must provide a statement at line 23 column 1'

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan Because you have terminated `for` loop with `;`. Remove it.

Comment: @Ashwini Thank you